# Save a fingerprint to the database of the fingerprint sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, library

I'm using the Adafruit Kookye fingerprint module in my project. Since it can only allocate 256 fingerprints I need to make a program to free the memory and add additional users. I have made the following function at the library:

```
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::downloadModel(uint16_t id, uint8_t packet_1[], uint8_t packet_2[], uint8_t slot) {
  uint8_t packet[] = {FINGERPRINT_DOWNLOAD, slot};
  writePacket(theAddress, FINGERPRINT_COMMANDPACKET, sizeof(packet)+2, packet);
  uint8_t len = getReply(recvPacket);

  if ((len != 1) && (recvPacket[0] != FINGERPRINT_ACKPACKET))
   return -1;
  if (recvPacket[1] == 0x00) {
    writePacket(theAddress, FINGERPRINT_DATAPACKET, sizeof(packet_1)+2, packet_1);
    writePacket(theAddress, FINGERPRINT_DATAPACKET, sizeof(packet_2)+2, packet_2);
    return recvPacket[1];
  } else {
    return recvPacket[1];
  }
}
```

This function is working, it puts the fingerprints to the buffer 1 and when I call the function to save with the ID it also works. When I print the fingerprints in the sensor, the structure is exactly the same as if they had been added directly from enrolling. However, when I serach the fingerprints the sensor always returns that the user does not exist.

I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: [Don't cross post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) Delete [your other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47818310).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sizeof()` operator doesn't do what you think it does. It's not a function that is executed at runtime, it's an operator that is interpreted at compile time.

It takes a variable and returns the size (in bytes) of that variable. Since you are passing it a pointer it gives you the size of that pointer. That's 2 bytes on an 8-bit system like the Uno.

In C an array is not a single entity with a size. It's a pointer to a block of memory that has been reserved at the time the array is declared. All you get is that pointer, and it's up to your program to remember the size.

You will have to pass the size of the arrays your `packet_1` and `packet_2` pointers are pointing to, or always assume that those arrays are the same size at all times.